# Generalized Stokes theorem in superspace

Tags: differential-geometry, field-theory, supersymmetry, superalgebra, superspace-formalism

Do the generalized Stokes theorem apply in superspace? Any issues or uncommon behaviour of the gradient, divergence and rotational in superspace?

Comment: The Supermanifold Version Of Stokes’s Theorem is here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.2199 (Witten, Notes On Supermanifolds and Integration). Try also with: https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.2544, https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.00966 and "Integration on supermanifolds" by Urs Schreiber: https://www.math.uni-hamburg.de/home/schreiber/sin.pdf (this website has further references: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/integration+over+supermanifolds).